# When to use “envisageable”?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

Is there any equivalence between these two sentences?

> *Ça te dit de commencer cet après-midi ?*
>
> *C’est envisageable pour toi de commencer cet après-midi ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ca te dit?* is a cheerful and informal suggestion - you wouldn't talk that way to a customer for instance - while *c'est envisageable?* denotes polite cautiousness.

Use *envisageable* when you are less sure of the answer and don't want to come across as pushy.

Comment: I do **not**, as far as I am concerned, read or hear any difference in matters of politeness or cautiousness.

Comment: Imagine working on a contract proposal for a client. Would you really write "nous pouvons commencer le 1er décembre si ça vous dit ?" ...

Comment: As part of a contract ? Ha! then what you mean is *formalism*. And you are correct. *Cela te dit* is indeed informal. (While remaining polite and cautious)

Comment: A contract was just an example. You wouldn't say "ça te dit?" without at least some reason to think that the answer will be positive.

Comment: When I say polite cautiousness, I'm referring to something specific - along the lines of "testing waters" or "prendre des pincettes". You basically have no idea of the answer.

Comment: @guillaume31 I am quite sure that there is no necessity in order to ask this type of question that you should know beforehand that the answer will be positive.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, il y a certainement et quelque part une sorte d'équivalence formelle... ne serait-ce que pour la raison qu'il s'agit de... deux questions.

Nota : Encore une fois, il est préférable d'éviter ce passe-partout de *est-ce que* pour systématiquement commencer une question. Ici, il n'apporte rien qu'un alourdissement disgracieux => Opter pour l'inversion typique d'une phrase interrogative :

*Est-ce envisageable pour toi de commencer cet après-midi?*

Pour ce qui est de la différence entre les deux formulations, je dirais que :

- *Est-ce envisageable ?* Laisse plutôt entendre une question portant sur les contraintes, les contingences de l'interlocuteur. (Le peut-il ? aurait-il le temps ? les moyens de locomotion...
- *Cela te dit* (que, pour ma part, je formulerais plutot : *Cela te dit-**il***) laissant plutôt entendre une question sur l'envie, le goût, le plaisir.

Comment: Je crois pouvoir être d'accord avec le fait que la forme « est-ce » (sans « que »); soit une forme élégante dont l'utilisation puisse être encouragée, mais je ne pense pas qu'il faille parler d'alourdissement et d'effet disgracieux  en ce qui concerne «est-ce que», cela est  répercuté sur les autres usages de cette forme et ce n'est pas vraiment le cas; la forme est un peu longue mais avec une bonne articulation on  ne s'y arrête pas le temps d'un souffle.

Comment: @user168676 : Oui, j'ai sans doute voulu faire trop court. En réalité, ce n'est pas *est-ce que* qui est lourd *en soi* mais le fait qu'ici, il va entraîner un redoublement inutile du verbe être : *est-ce que c'est...* C'est bien *est-ce que c'est* qui est lourd. Et ce que ne fait qu'apporter cette lourdeur-là.

Comment: Je n'hésiterais pas à vous suivre si vous vous en teniez à la logique et  je dirais même sur ce plan, balourd; mais je parle de  langue en temps que son dont les codes sont des quasi équivalents aux concepts manipulés, tout au moins une partie du temps; c'est à dire, qu'en particulier pour l'enfant et  l'adulte qui n'est pas un analyste du langage, le son évoque la même chose que « est-ce » et ils n'ont pas cette impression ni non plus ne la donnent à quiconque sans une loupe fixée sur la langue; je dois avouer que je suis moi-même sujet à cette psychologie de la langue.

Comment: @user168676 : "*psychologie de la langue*"... "*son dont les codes sont des quasis équivalents aux concepts...*" Vous voulez parler des digrammes ? Pure curiosité sans évidemment obligation de répondre : Quelle est votre langue maternelle ?

Comment: Les états de chose  dont je fais part ne sont que le produit de mes réflexions personnelles et je suis donc dépourvu du vocabulaire technique de base dans ce domaine; je ne sais pas ce que « digramme » signifie; ma langue maternelle est le français. (Je viens de vérifier le mot; non, il ne s'agit pas de digrammes.)

Answer (score 1):

They are close but not strictly equivalent.

The first question is asking about the willingness/desire of the person while the second one is asking about his/her opinion about the practicability of the event.

Comment: On n'est pas un service de correction. Ce serait mieux de se contenter de répondre à la question posée sans se perdre longuement dans des considérations annexes qui n'ont pas de rapport avec la question.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je comprends et du coup, j'efface toute cette partie de ma réponse. Comme on corrige en général les erreurs de français présentes dans les questions, on est quand même un petit peu aussi un service de correction... et ne pas les corriger serait pire.

Comment: Un peu, mais ce n'est pas notre but.  Quelqu'un qui tombe sur cette question en cherchant « envisageable » n'est pas intéressé par les erreurs annexes.